# How to bind two variables in a template ( angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple template as following :

```
      <ul ng-repeat="email in emails">
      <br>Email ID {{email.EmailsID}} <br>
       Unread {{email.Unread}}
       <ul>
```

The issue is that I need to fetch the data in two calls: The list of  `EmailsID` from an API and the `Unread` value of each `EmailsID` from another API. Any idea how to make this work ? I've tried something below and I can fetch the the `EmailsID` but I don't know how to merge it with the unread value of each emailsId from the `syncAPI`. Currently I've hardcoded the emailsId value to 9 in the API URL as can be seen below `http://local.app.com:8080/imap/syncAPI?emailsId=9`

```
var crmApp = angular.module('crmApp', []);

crmApp.controller('EmailsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/emailsAPI', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(data) {
 var index;
for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
$http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/messages/imap/syncAPI?emailsId='+data.EmailsID+'&mailbox=inbox', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(unreadD) {

 data[index].unread = unreadD;
   $scope.emails = data;
      });
});
```

I'm new to angularjs and javascript

Comment: Create a service to return a combined array and then use this array for `ng-repeat` iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are iterating a series of asynchronous callbacks wherein each callback will definitely refer to `index = emails.length` when it gets invoked. i.e. all your callbacks will refer to `$scope.emails[data.length] = unreadD`.

Instead of using a for loop as an iterator you can use `angular.forEach()`.

```
var crmApp = angular.module('crmApp', []);

crmApp.controller('EmailsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/emailsAPI', {withCredentials: true})
    .success(function(emails) {
       $scope.emails = emails;
       angular.forEach(emails, function(email) {
          $http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/imap/syncAPI?emailsId=' + email.EmailsID + '&mailbox=inbox', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(unreadD) {
            email.Unread = unreadD;
          });
       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the output of your first call to `emailsAPI` for your second call to `syncAPI`. In order to achieve this put the call to `syncAPI` in your success callback for `emailsAPI` like so:

```
var crmApp = angular.module('crmApp', []);

crmApp.controller('EmailsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var getReadStatus = function(emails) {
    $scope.emails=emails;
    for(var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      $http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/imap/syncAPI?emailsId=' + emails[i].EmailsID + '&mailbox=inbox', {withCredentials: true}).success(function(unreadD) {
        $scope.emails[i].Unread = unreadD;
      });
    }
  }

  $http.get('http://local.app.com:8080/emailsAPI', {withCredentials:true}).success(function(data) {
    getReadStatus(data);
  });
}
```

The `getReadStatus` function here will assign all of the emails recieved from the first API call to the same variable as before (`$scope.emails`) it will then cycle through each email object, and use the `EmailsID` property to call the second API. Finally it will add a property called `Unread` to each `email` object allowing it to be accessed correctly from the template.

Comment: it says ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `` on line 11 ( mine ) ``  for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {``

Comment: whoops, I was stuck in java land, I've edited to use `var` instead of `int`. Try that.

Comment: ``ReferenceError: getReadStatus is not defined``